# Angular ng-repeat with input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view like this:

```
<table class="table">
   <tr data-ng-repeat="exercise in exercises x">
      <td>
           <input type="number" data-ng-model="?????????" />
       </td>
        <td>
           {{exercise.Name}}
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

I'm wondering what should I put as `data-ng-model` so I can use two-way data binding i.e., the input's value, in my controller?

I've tried  `data-ng-model="{{exercise.Name}}"` but that resulted in errors.

Also, how can I reference certain input in the controller? Can I do something like this: `$scope.InputOne = ...`

Comment: I was away from the PC ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for two-way-bind use ng-model, and one-way-bind use ng-bind or {{}} brackets.

this [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LfGaE) demonstrates to use the two ways and how to get information of the object.

ps: the controller should not "see" the view directly.

```
<body data-ng-app="app">
 <div data-ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="exercise in exercises">
        <td>
           <input type="number" data-ng-model="exercise.Name" />
        </td>
        <td data-ng-bind="exercise.Name"></td>
        <td><button data-ng-click="getInformation($index)">Get information</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.exercises = [{Name:1},
                    {Name:2},
                    {Name:3},
                    {Name:4}
];

$scope.getInformation = function(index) {
  alert($scope.exercises[index].Name);
}        
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `data-ng-model="exercise.Name"` without the {{}} brackets.

I suggest you start at the [angular tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, please can you tell me how can I get data for particular input in controller ?